# FLOPs in Tensor Flow Convolution Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, flops

I am wondering about the number of float operations in Tensorflow Convolutional layers.

As I am waiting for this functionality to be released on TF 2.x, I tried it out for TF 1.x, and I came to outcomes that I do not understand how is being computed, and one of them is very impressive (check Q3).

I have the following code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        InputLayer((32, 32, 1)),
        # Conv2D(1, 5, padding='same'),
        # Flatten(),
        # Dense(1, activation='softmax')
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy')

opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()
profile = tf.profiler.profile(tf.get_default_graph(), tf.RunMetadata(), cmd='op', options=opts)
profile.total_float_ops
```

Complete Gist here:

https://colab.research.google.com/gist/eduardo4jesus/6721ec992c402bcdc834ab2edbc1b2b4/tf1-flops.ipynb

What is the explanation for the results bellow?

1. If I run the code above, only with the `InputLayer` uncommented, the FLOPS output is `2`.

> Q1: Why `2`?

2. If I run the code as bellow, the output is `2050`.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        InputLayer((32, 32, 1)),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(1, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

> Q2: Why `2050?`? I was expecting `1026` from `1024` plus those unexplained `2`. These 1024 would be from the weights of the dense layer, since we have one neurone is one parameter per each input feature, therefore, `1024`. Again, why double? (Back propagation??)

3. The most intriguing and important one. If I run the code as bellow, the output is `2101`.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        InputLayer((32, 32, 1)),
        Conv2D(1, 5, padding='same'),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(1, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

> Q3: Why `2101?`? I was expecting `2050 + 1024 x 5` which is way greater than only `2101`. The convolution layer itself should yield `N*N*K*K` where `N=32` and `K=5`. How come the model takes less FLOPs than only the last layer, given that the convolution produces the same shape of its input? What kind of crazy optimization it has?

[Update]

When printing profile I have these nodes contributing to `total_float_ops`. Most of them (see bellow) are associated with the `Initializer`, not the Model computation itself.

```
name: "_TFProfRoot"
total_float_ops: 2101
children {
  name: "Mul"
  float_ops: 1050
  total_float_ops: 2101
  graph_nodes {
    name: "conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul"
    float_ops: 25
    total_float_ops: 25
    input_shapes {
      key: 0
      value {
        dim {
          size: 5
        }
        dim {
          size: 5
        }
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
    input_shapes {
      key: 1
      value {
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
    total_definition_count: 1
  }
  graph_nodes {
    name: "dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul"
    float_ops: 1024
    total_float_ops: 1024
    input_shapes {
      key: 0
      value {
        dim {
          size: 1024
        }
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
    input_shapes {
      key: 1
      value {
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
    total_definition_count: 1
  }
  graph_nodes {
    name: "loss/dense_loss/weighted_loss/Mul"
    input_shapes {
      key: 0
      value {
        dim {
          size: -1
        }
      }
    }
    input_shapes {
      key: 1
      value {
        dim {
          size: -1
        }
      }
    }
    total_definition_count: 1
  }
  graph_nodes {
    name: "loss/dense_loss/weighted_loss/broadcast_weights"
    input_shapes {
      key: 0
      value {
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
    input_shapes {
      key: 1
      value {
        dim {
          size: -1
        }
      }
    }
    total_definition_count: 1
  }
  graph_nodes {
    name: "loss/mul"
    float_ops: 1
    total_float_ops: 1
    input_shapes {
      key: 0
      value {
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
    input_shapes {
      key: 1
      value {
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
    total_definition_count: 1
  }
  children {
    name: "Add"
    float_ops: 1049
    total_float_ops: 1051
    graph_nodes {
      name: "conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform"
      float_ops: 25
      total_float_ops: 25
      input_shapes {
        key: 0
        value {
          dim {
            size: 5
          }
          dim {
            size: 5
          }
          dim {
            size: 1
          }
          dim {
            size: 1
          }
        }
      }
      input_shapes {
        key: 1
        value {
          dim {
            size: 1
          }
        }
      }
      total_definition_count: 1
    }
    graph_nodes {
      name: "dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform"
      float_ops: 1024
      total_float_ops: 1024
      input_shapes {
        key: 0
        value {
          dim {
            size: 1024
          }
          dim {
            size: 1
          }
        }
      }
      input_shapes {
        key: 1
        value {
          dim {
            size: 1
          }
        }
      }
      total_definition_count: 1
    }
    children {
      name: "Sub"
      float_ops: 2
      total_float_ops: 2
      graph_nodes {
        name: "conv2d/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub"
        float_ops: 1
        total_float_ops: 1
        input_shapes {
          key: 0
          value {
            dim {
              size: 1
            }
          }
        }
        input_shapes {
          key: 1
          value {
            dim {
              size: 1
            }
          }
        }
        total_definition_count: 1
      }
      graph_nodes {
        name: "dense/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub"
        float_ops: 1
        total_float_ops: 1
        input_shapes {
          key: 0
          value {
            dim {
              size: 1
            }
          }
        }
        input_shapes {
          key: 1
          value {
            dim {
              size: 1
            }
          }
        }
        total_definition_count: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this API is, at best, experimental.

Q1. No idea where 2 is coming from.

Q2. 2 is related to Input as we saw. 2048 left. Your input size is 32*32*1 which is 1024 flattened. Your calculation is x*W+b, where x is [1024], corresponding W is [1, 1024]. Operation of x*W would lead to 1024 multiplications and 1024 additions. Bias add seems to be ignored, because it should otherwise result in total of 2051 ops: 2+1024+1024+1.

Q3. I changed your filter size to 3 and got 21 flops, which is quit ridiculous. The number didn't change for CPU/GPU executor. My conclusion would be that Convolutional layers do not produce believable numbers.

```
tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        InputLayer((32, 32, 1)),
        Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same'),
        Flatten(),
    ]) # => 21 ops



tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    InputLayer((32, 32, 1)),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same'),
    Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same'),
    Flatten(),
]) # => 1.09K ops
```